# Android: click on one MenuItem to make another MenuItem visible in the toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-menu

Example:

- Menu1 (visible = false)
- Menu2 (visible = false)
- Menu3 (visible = true)

When click on Menu3, I want Menu1 and Menu2 to be displayed.

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem Menu1 = menu.findItem(R.id.Menu1);
    MenuItem Menu2 = menu.findItem(R.id.Menu2);

    Menu1.setVisible(false);
    Menu2.setVisible(false);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.Menu3) {
        item.setVisible(false);
        Menu menu;
        menu.findItem(R.id.Menu1).setVisible(true);

        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The following code is not working:

```
Menu menu;
menu.findItem(R.id.Menu1).setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Are you sure `onOptionsItemSelected` gets called?

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
Menu menu;
menu.findItem(R.id.Menu1).setVisible(true);
```

Will not work as the `menu` varaible is not initialized. You should initialize the `menu` variable as needed and then call to setVisible method.